# jsp with ajax two simultaneous requests only getting one response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest, simultaneous

I have a jsp page where I'm trying to send multiple  (two currently) ajax requests at once, but I only seem to get the second response.  [This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/121613/HTML-JavaScript/simultaneous-ajax-requests) guy described my problem exactly, but his solution didn't work for me.

Here is my js code:

```
function createRequestObject(){
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
        //Error for an old browser
        alert('Browser error');
    }

    return req;
}

function sendRequest(method, url, d){
    var http = createRequestObject();
    var div = d;

    if(method == 'get' || method == 'GET'){
        http.open(method, url, true);

        http.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
                var response = http.responseText;
                if(response){
                    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = response;
                }
            }
        };

        http.send(null);
    }
}
```

And here is how I call that code:

```
QC1 Status: <div id='qc1'>blah</div> 
<br />UAT2 Status: <div id='uat2'>blah2</div>

<a onclick="sendRequest('GET','index.jsp?qc1.properties=true','qc1'); " href="#">qc1</a>
<a onclick="sendRequest('GET','index.jsp?uat2.properties=true','uat2'); " href="#">uat2</a>
<a onclick="sendRequest('GET','index.jsp?qc1.properties=true','qc1'); sendRequest('GET','index.jsp?uat2.properties=true','uat2'); " href="#">both</a>
```

When I call one at a time they work as expected, but the "both" link only updates with the second request, even though I know it runs the index.jsp code for both.

EDIT: Ok, after fixing the obvious mistake that BalusC pointed out, it works.  Fixed it in this post too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indeed sending two requests on the **same URL** and updating the **same div**. Shouldn't the first one go to the `qc1` one and update the `qc1` one?

Comment: wow... I want to cry about the two hours i've wasted.  thank you! (this mistake was so obvious I feel the need to defend myself: had the two requests going to the right places before, but had the js wrong, and then by the time I had fixed the js to where it should work, I had redone the page with the two calling requests and failed horribly)

Comment: @epascarello: really? With "update" I meant the div id which is passed as second argument. I rollbacked your edit.